# Calculate relative positions using xlsxwriter

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I'm referring [this link](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/example_chart_pie.html) to draw a pie chart and bar chart below each pie chart.

I've the data which is dynamic, means I can have even 1 pie+bar chart or multiple, depending upon the data I receive.

In the link provided, the placement of location is hardcoded, ie one pie chart at C2 and the other at C18. I dont want to hardcode it rather provide a dynamic value which should place the next pie chart after leaving 2-3 lines.

While using reportlabs to generate PDF, I used `showPage()` to start from the next page. Is there anything like this in xlsxwriter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the link provided, the placement of location is hardcoded, ie one pie chart at C2
>   and the other at C18. I dont want to hardcode it rather provide a dynamic value which
>   should place the next pie chart after leaving 2-3 lines.

Like the majority of XlsxWriter methods [`insert_chart()`](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/worksheet.html#worksheet-insert_chart) accepts [(row, column) notation as wll as "A1" notation](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/working_with_cell_notation.html). So you can position acharts as follows:

```
worksheet.insert_chart(3, 4, chart)
```

If you have a number of charts that you want to position close to each other then you can do something like this:

```
chart_row = 1
chart_col = 3
chart_offset = 0;

worksheet.insert_chart(chart_row + chart_offset, chart_col, chart1)

# Later...

chart_offset += 15
worksheet.insert_chart(chart_row + chart_offset, chart_col, chart2)
```

You can also position charts within cells using the `offset` options shown in the example you linked to.

Refer to the [Chart API](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/chart.html) and [Working with Charts](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/working_with_charts.html) documentation for more information.

> While using reportlabs to generate PDF, I used showPage() to start from the next page.
>   Is there anything like this in xlsxwriter?

You can set page breaks in the worksheet using the [`set_h_pagebreaks()`](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/page_setup.html#worksheet-set-h-pagebreaks) method.

Comment: I figured that outbefore you posted. Thanks Anyways. :)